# Creating an operator for a polarizing beam splitter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

I am trying to make a polarizing beam splitter operator but all my approaches have failed so far. I will try to explain what I have done, and hopefully there are people out there that can point out my mistakes and/or suggest better methods.
I do all calculations in QuTiP, but any help regarding the theory is highly appreciated.

Let's take the case with two polarized photons input to a polarizing beam splitter. They can be in the states $\left|V\right>$  (vertically polarized), $\left|H\right>$ (horizontally polarized) or a superposition of the two. $\left|H\right>$  is defined as a (2x1) vector, a so called "Quantum Object" in QuTiP: `Qobj([[0], [1]])`  and $\left|V\right>$ is  `Qobj([[1], [0]])`. The input state is the tensor product of the two states, with the subscripts denoting the ports, for example: $\left| H \right>_a \left| H \right>_b$.

The inputs are at port a and b, and outputs at port c and d.
Using this, I have constructed this unitary PBS operator:

$$
\hat{O}_{PBS} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & i
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The i's are the phases comming from the reflections, and the rows are ordered in the following way: $\left( \left| H \right>_a, \left| H \right>_b, \left| V \right>_a, \left| V \right>_b \right)$ to $\left( \left| H \right>_c, \left| H \right>_d, \left| V \right>_c, \left| V \right>_d \right)$.

At port a, just before the PBS, I put a half-wave plate (HWP) to rotate the polarization of one of the photons. The operator looks like this:

$$
\hat{O}_{HWP} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(2\theta) & \sin(2\theta)  \\
    \sin(2\theta) & \cos(2\theta)  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle with which the HWP is rotated.

So if I input two horizontally polarized photons, the state after the PBS is:

$$
\left| \psi \right> = 
\left(\hat{O}_{HWP} \otimes \mathbb{1} \right) \hat{O}_{PBS}
\left| H \right>_a \left| H \right>_b
$$
($\hat{O}_{HWP}$ only acts on the state at port a)

At port c and d, I measure the output the following way:

1. I make a density matrix from the output state:
   $$
   \rho = \left| \psi \right> \left< \psi \right|
   $$
2. and a measurement operator that measures only a certain polarization at both output ports, c and d, for example $\left| H \right>$:

$$
\hat{M} = \left| H \right> \left< H \right|
$$

3. The expectation value, I find by tracing:

$$
m = tr \left( \hat{M} \rho \right)
$$

In my calculations, I change the polarization of the photon at port a by iterating $\theta$ from 0 to $\pi$ and then I evaluate the expectation value at each step.
For $\left| H \right>$ input at port a and b, respectively, and measuring  $\left| H \right>$ at both output ports, I get:

[image: |H> input at port a and b, respectively, and projection onto |H> at port c and d, respectively.]

But the weird thing happens when I input $\left| V \right>$ at port a and b, respectively, and measure $\left| V \right>$ at both output ports:

[image: |V> input at port a and b, respectively, and projection onto |V> at port c and d, respectively.]

Here the expectation value is constant.

**So my questions are:**

1. What am I doing wrong in my calculations?
2. Do I construct the PBS operator the correct way?
3. If I were to only do a measurement at port c, I would have to project the state at port d onto $\mathbb{1}$. The problem is the fact that the measurement operator is the outer product of two (2x1) vectors, and I cannot make $\mathbb{1}$ as a (2x1) vector. How can I make a measurement operator, that projects the state after the PBS onto for example $\left| H \right>$ at port c and $\mathbb{1}$ at port d?
4. When I have a well functioning PBS operator, how do I include losses in it?

Please let me know if I need to elaborate on something. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How do you describe if two photons go to the same port?  Your encoding does not seem to allow for two-photon states.  Usually beam splitters are written in second quantization (i.e., transforming the creation operators for the field).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: do you mind providing an answer in which you describe this second quantization approach to represent a beam splitter?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I'm just guessing, but maybe the photons are approaching the beam splitter from opposite directions.

Comment: the way you written $|\psi\rangle$ does not make much sense: each state like $|H_a\rangle$ and $|H_b\rangle$ lives in a 4-dimensional space, as do the operators $O_{PBS}$ and $1\otimes O_{HWP}$. On the other hand, $|H_a\rangle|H_b\rangle$ is a state in a seemingly $8$-dimensional space, so how did you compute the product there?

Comment: @flippiefanus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter#Quantum_mechanical_description

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: thanks, however that does not seem to work for the general case.

Comment: @flippiefanus Which general case? Why not?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: it does not seem to give the right results for Fock states, because it allows unprocessed photons to pass through.

Comment: @flippiefanus What are unprocessed photons? Is this like unpasteurized milk?  And yes, this is the correct way to describe a beam splitter quantum mechanically.  This means that it works in the general case.  If it wouldn't work for some cases, it wouldn't be correct.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch This only describes two photons going to the beam splitter from each their ports; port a and b. But yes, when one is $\left| H \right>$ and one is $\left| V \right>$, the photons will go to the same output port. Therefore, I tried another approach that includes two photon states. One challenge has been to define the vacuum state. I ended up defining both the vacuum state, ∣H⟩ and ∣V⟩ as 3 dimensional vectors (still in QuTiP), with vacuum being Qobj([[1], [0], [0]]), ∣H⟩=Qobj([[0], [1], [0]]) and ∣V⟩=Qobj([[0], [0], [1]]). The beam splitter operator then becomes an 81x81 matrix.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch ... I still haven't implemented it, but I am still unsure as to how to include losses in this operator (so adding percentages of reflectivity and transitivity) and still have a unitary operator.

Comment: @glS $\left| H \right>_a$ and $ \left| H \right>_b$ each live in a 2-dim. space, so $\left| H \right>_a \left| H \right>_b$ (remember the tensor product) lives in a 4-dim. space. So does $\hat{O}_{PBS}$ and $\hat{O}_{HWP} \otimes \mathbb{1}$, respectively. Therefore, it is possible to compute the product as I write it above in the description.

Comment: @user198150 no they don't. You need one two-dimensional space to specify the polarization dof and another one to specify the mode ($a$ or $b$), thus there is a total of four possible modes, and vectors such as $|H\rangle_a$ have to live in a 4-dimensional space to both specify polarization and mode

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Correction: the definitions are ∣V⟩=Qobj([[0], [1], [0]]) and ∣H⟩=Qobj([[0], [0], [1]]), as is suggested in the QuTiP documentation. I wanted to use creation- and annihilation operators in QuTiP to define the PBS-operator, but they don't distinguish between polarization when acting on states, so I retrieved to the method I describe above.

Comment: @glS okay, this might be where the core of my problem is, thanks for pointing it out. In this 4-dim. vector, do these definitions look right: $\left| V \right>_a$=[1;0;0;0], $\left| H \right>_a$=[0;1;0;0], $\left| V \right>_b$=[0;0;1;0], $\left| H \right>_b$=[0;0;0;1] ?

Comment: @user198150 yes, that looks correct. I wrote an answer addressing what I believe was the main misconception here. I did not describe in detail how the formalisms to describe the evolution of many-boson states works, as that would be lengthy and likely fall outside the scope of this question. If you can't find descriptions of how that works around the site feel free to ask it as a separate question

Comment: @glS I'm new to this website and just saw your answer.. Thank you very much!! Yes, in my case I will have two indistinguishable photons as input to the PBS, so I will try to follow your advice and see if I can manage to do the calculation right. If I get stuck again, another question will probably pop up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A formalism like the one you use in your question, once a few mistakes are amended, will allow you to correctly describe the evolution of *single-photon* states.

In particular, the state of a single photon with two spatial degrees of freedom and two possible polarization states is described as a vector in a four-dimensional space.
A possible convention is to use
$$
|V\rangle_a=(1,0,0,0)^T, \\
|H\rangle_a= (0,1,0,0)^T, \\
|V\rangle_b=(0,0,1,0)^T, \\
|H\rangle_b= (0,0,0,1)^T.
$$
You can then use the evolution matrix you gave to describe the evolution of any input photon through the PBS.

However, this will not work as soon as you have multiple *indistinguishable* photons as inputs.
The reason is that the space of possible modes of many indistinguishable photons (or, more generally, bosons) is smaller than the tensor product of the spaces of the single photons.
Roughly speaking, this is because if the photons are indistinguishable, states like $|H_a\rangle|V_b\rangle$ and $|V_b\rangle|H_a\rangle$ are actually the same state.

To properly describe the evolution of many-boson states you need to take into account their indistinguishability.
This can be done in several equivalent ways:
1) using second quantization formalism, which automatically takes into account the symmetry properties of the states, 2) using the unitary evolution that properly describes how many-boson basis states evolve, or 3) keep using the standard formalism, but only computing the amplitudes between *symmetrized* input and output states.